# Powershell Encoding Default Output

Tags: powershell, encoding, tfs

I have the following problems with a powershell script that runs inside a TFS build. Both problems are unrelated to TFS and can be reproduced using an simple powershell command line window.

1) Completely unrelated to TFS. It seems Powershell does not like german umlauts when it comes to pipe.

1a) This line of code works fine and all umlauts are shown correctly

```
.\TF.exe hist "$/Test" /recursive /collection:https://TestTFS/tfs/TestCollection /noprompt /version:C1~T
```

1b) This line messes with umlauts

```
.\TF.exe hist "$/Test" /recursive /collection:https://TestTFS/tfs/TestCollection /noprompt /version:C1~T | Out-String
```

Initially I tried Out-File and changed encoding only to the that the umlauts are encoded wrong in every typeset (UTF8, unicode, UTF32,...)

I really do not know how to extract a string from standard output and get the umlauts right.

2) When using Out-File or Out-String each line in the output got truncated after 80 characters with seems to be the default screen buffer setting. How can I change that inside a powershell script and why does it even have an impact when redirecting the output.

Comment: "messes with umlauts": please show us, otherwise we're guessing. Also note `tf.exe` is not part of PowerShell, it is just a Windows console executable: you'll likely need to understand how it encodes its output to read it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Problem number 2 is not a Powershell problem. [tfs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/history-command) says following about default `/format` parameter (i.e. `/format:brief`)

> Some of the data may be truncated.

`/format:detailed` does not have that warning, but it returns more information, which you can process with Powershell before doing `Out-String` or `Out-File`.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

The following should solve both your problems, which stem from `tf.exe` using *ANSI* character encoding rather than the expected *OEM* encoding, and from truncating output by default.:

- If you're using ***Windows PowerShell*** (the Windows-only legacy edition of PowerShell with versions up to v5.1):

```sh
$correctlyCapturedOutput = 
  & {
    $prev = [Console]::OutputEncoding
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default

    # Note the addition of /format:detailed
    .\tf.exe hist '$/Test' /recursive /collection:https://TestTFS/tfs/TestCollection /noprompt /format:detailed /version:C1~T

    [Console]::OutputEncoding = $prev
  }
```

- If you're using the cross-platform, install-on-demand **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**:

  - Note: `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default`, which reports the active *ANSI* code page's encoding in Windows PowerShell, reports (BOM-less) UTF-8 in PowerShell (Core) (reflecting .NET Core's / .NET 5+'s behavior). Therefore, the active ANSI code page must be determined explicitly, which is most robustly done via the registry.

```sh
$correctlyCapturedOutput = 
  & {
    $prev = [Console]::OutputEncoding
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(
      [int] ((Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage ACP).ACP)
    )

    # Note the addition of /format:detailed
    .\tf.exe hist '$/Test' /recursive /collection:https://TestTFS/tfs/TestCollection /noprompt /format:detailed /version:C1~T

    [Console]::OutputEncoding = $prev
  }
```

---

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/ef57aea441ea8bd43387a7d7edfc6c19/raw/Invoke-WithEncoding.ps1) contains **helper function `Invoke-WithEncoding`**, which can simplify the above in both PowerShell edition as follows:

```sh
$correctlyCapturedOutput = 
  Invoke-WithEncoding -Encoding Ansi {
    .\tf.exe hist '$/Test' /recursive /collection:https://TestTFS/tfs/TestCollection /noprompt /format:detailed /version:C1~T
  }
```

You can directly download and define the function with the following command (while I can personally assure you that doing so is safe, it is advisable to check the source code first):

```
# Downloads and defines function Invoke-WithEncoding in the current session.
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/ef57aea441ea8bd43387a7d7edfc6c19/raw/Invoke-WithEncoding.ps1 | iex
```

Read on for a detailed discussion.

---

**Re the umlaut (character encoding) problem:**

**While the output from external programs may *print* OK to the *console*, when it comes to *capturing the output in a variable or redirecting it*** - such as sending it through the pipeline to `Out-String` in your case - **PowerShell *decodes the output into .NET strings*, using the character encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`**.

If `[Console]::OutputEncoding` doesn't match the actual encoding used by the external program, PowerShell will *misinterpret* the output.

The solution is to **(temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to the actual encoding used by the external program**.

While the [official `tf.exe` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands) doesn't discuss character encodings, this [comment on GitHub](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/80) suggests that `tf.exe` uses the system's active ANSI code page, such as Windows-1252 on US-English or Western European systems.

It should be noted that the **use of the *ANSI* code page is *nonstandard* behavior for a *console* application**, because console applications are expected to use the system's active *OEM* code page.  As an aside: `python` too exhibits this nonstandard behavior by default, though its behavior is configurable.

The solutions at the top show how to temporarily switch `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to the active ANSI code page's encoding in order to ensure that PowerShell correctly decodes `tf.exe`'s output.

---

**Re output-line truncation with `Out-String` / `Out-File` (and therefore also `>` and `>>`):**

- As [Mustafa Zengin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48516405/45375) points out, **in your particular case - due to use of `tf.exe` - the truncation happens at the *source***, i.e. it is `tf.exe` itself that outputs truncated data per its default formatting (implied `/format:brief` when `/noprompt` is also specified).
- **In general, [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) and [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) / `>` / `>>` do *situationally* truncate or line-wrap their output lines based on the console-window width** (with a default of `120` chars. in the absence of a console):

  - Truncation of line-wrapping applies only to output lines stemming from the representations of *non-primitive, non-string* objects generated by PowerShell's rich output-formatting system:
  - *Strings themselves* (`[string]` input) as well as the *string representations of .NET primitive types (plus a few more singe-value-only types)* are *not* subject to truncation / line-wrapping.
- **Since PowerShell only ever interprets output from *external programs* as *text* (`[string]` instances), truncation / line-wrapping do *not* occur**.

  - It follows that **there's usually no reason to use `Out-String` on external-program output** - unless you need to join the stream (array) of output lines to form a *single, multiline* string for further in-memory processing.
  - However, note that **`Out-String` *invariably adds a trailing newline* to the resulting string**, which may be undesired; use `(...) -join [Environment]::NewLine` to avoid that; `Out-String`'s problematic behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).